# MessageBox.Show flavor that shows up on the taskbar

Tags: .net, taskbar, messagebox

Is there a way to call MessageBox.Show that appears in the taskbar?

It would probably be best to just create a custom form and display it of course, but being a lazy programmer I want to avoid redoing the default Error and Alert notification icons you get with a good old fashioned MessageBox.Show call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [MessageBoxOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxoptions.aspx) enum:

```
MessageBox.Show("Test", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information,
    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
```

**Note:** There are some multi threading side effect to the usage of this, see the article [How To Display A User Interface From A Daemon](http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith.GuideBook/HowToDisplayAUserInterfaceFromADaemon.html).

Comment: Apparently, any MessageBox.Show without a parent specified appears in the taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

Implement an IWin32Window, return the handle as IntPtr.Zero (desktop), then display the message box with that window as the parent.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static Image GetImage(MessageBoxIcon icon)
{
    switch (icon)
    {
        case MessageBoxIcon.Error:
            return System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Error.ToBitmap();
        case MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation:
            return System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Exclamation.ToBitmap();
        case MessageBoxIcon.Information:
            return System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Information.ToBitmap();
        case MessageBoxIcon.Question:
            return System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Question.ToBitmap();
    }
    return null;
}
```