# Issue with Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox method

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, taskbar

'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox' method always brings up windows taskbar when any message is displayed. How to fix this issue? I want the message to be the top most but windows taskbar shouldn't be visible.

Appreciate your help!!

Comment: No repro.  How did you cover/hide the taskbar?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649658/messagebox-show-flavor-that-shows-up-on-the-taskbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you are using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox?  I would avoid using the Microsoft.VisualBasic library as much as possible.  It's mainly there for backward compatibility.  Almost everything in Microsoft.VisualBasic has been replaced in the .Net Framework elsewhere.

For example the MessageBox is now in System.Windows.Forms.

To force it on top always.....  try the [MessageBoxOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxoptions.aspx) of DefaultDesktopOnly

or this little [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/TopMostMessageBox.aspx) sample.

To hide the message box from the windows task bar you might need to pass in the form you are calling the message box from in the call to [Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dac1663(v=VS.80).aspx) (owner parameter).  If the message box doesn't have an owner it will display on the task bar as it's own form.

Comment: Okey, How to make sure the message box is top most with MessageBox of System.Windows.Forms. Sometimes, the message box displayed behind the window/form.

Comment: Thanks, With your approach of using MessageBoxOptions of DefaultDesktopOnly also the message box shows up in the windows taskbar. How to avoid this?

Comment: This fixes it so that it forces it to show on top now but You don't want the messagebox to show in the windows taskbar?

Comment: Yes, I don't want the messagebox to show in the windows taskbar.